# How to resolve dependency version conflict in composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am currently developing a Laravel application which has following package requirements in composer.json

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
"phpspec/phpspec": "2.5.*",
"sebastian/exporter": "~2.0"
```

Now, problem is that `phpunit` requires `exporter 2.0` and the package `phpspec` requires `exporter 1.0`.

So, now these requirements are conflicting and I am unable to update the packages.

How should I resolve this conflict and install these packages?

**Note:** I noticed that from the composer.json of `phpspec` that it has requirements defined as `~1.0|~2.0` for `exporter`. So it should work with both but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: its totally normal no?
phpspec designed for export 1.0 and  you cant use it with export 2.0. 

think about it you bought a game which works on Windows XP but you try to use it on Windows 10 unless there is patch or new version of this game you cant play it. (dont tell me about simulation mode etc :p  just giving you an example)

Comment: @Rodrane Yes I totally understand that and I was expecting it to work like this. But composer id denying installation of both `exporter` and `phpspec`

Comment: because its not normal to have same libraries 2 different versions. if namespaces are same in both versions (which probably it is) vendor autoload would be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a phpspec version that supports `sebastian/exporter` 2.x, you have to use [3.2.2 or higher](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/releases/tag/3.2.2).

Comment: Yeah. I just figured that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if `phpspec` allows exporter `~1.0` then why don't you just use it

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
"phpspec/phpspec": "2.5.*",
"sebastian/exporter": "~1.0"
```

Comment: Because `phpunit` requires `exporter 2.0` which `phpspec` is denying.

Comment: maybe you could downgrade your phpunit version too ?

Comment: @Rodrane But I am already using the least required version for Laravel 5.4